# Coordinates won't change when rotated Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, catransform3d

I am rotating a wheel which various subviews (UIImageViews and UIButtons)
However when I ask it to display each and every centre of every subview, it is giving me the same value everytime.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {   
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    int len = [allTouches count]-1;

    UITouch *touch =[[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:len];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[self superview]];
    float theAngle = atan2( location.y-self.center.y, location.x-self.center.x );

    totalRadians = theAngle;

    [self rotateImage:theAngle];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

-(void) rotateImage:(float)angleRadians{

    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleRadians);
    CATransform3D rotatedTransform = self.layer.transform;
    self.layer.transform = rotatedTransform;    
    int count = 0;
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
    count++;    
        //these values are always the same
    NSLog(@"%i %f %f", count, subview.center.x, subview.center.y);
    }
}
```

May someone please tell me why the values are always coming the same even after being rotated and placed in a different position?

Thanks!

Comment: Setting the layer transform to a purely-rotational transform always rotates about the current center of the layer. You don't appear to be applying any translational transforms. What behavior were you expecting?

Comment: Because I am rotating an imageview which contains various components. These components should change their coordinations. Am I making any sense?

Comment: The center of a subview is expressed relative to its superview's coordinate space. So although the subviews move in screen space, they do not move relative to their parent unless you explicitly apply a rotation to them. For most use cases, it makes sense for subviews to maintain their relative position.

Comment: but if the superview has been rotated, their coordinates would change right? That is what I am trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

To go off what was being said in the comments, center is expressed within the superview bounds. Bounds are not affected by rotation, {0,0} is always the upper left of the view.

To get what you want, you need to apply the rotation to the center point,

`rotatedCenter = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(subview.center, self.transform);`

Comment: thnx so this in other words will find the correct coordinates of the center according to the transformation whihc has happened?

Comment: It should. This will also work for any transformation not just the rotation.

Comment: wow this looks good. thanks. one last question please. if i am receiving negative numbers, is this correct? or am i doing something wrong and thus yielding an incorrect result?

Comment: negatives certainly are possible

Comment: but this does not get the coordinates of the object with respect to the entire page, correct? just with respect to itself